# How do I integration test a ASP 5/Core Web API with [Authorize] Attributes

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, owin, asp.net5, owin-middleware

I currently have an ASP 5/ASP Core Web API that I need to integration test with the OWIN Test Server.

The problem is that I use IdentityServer as the authorization server in production and I do not want to include the authorization as part of my integration testing.

This is the Startup.cs of the API:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Set up configuration sources.
    IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true);

    if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
    {
        // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
        builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
    }

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build().ReloadOnChanged("appsettings.json");
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    ConfigureEntityFrameworkDatabase(services, Configuration);

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<HoehenSuchtIdentityDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    ConfigureMvc(services);

    // register autofac as dependency resolver
    ContainerBuilder containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // register all required autofac modules
    RegisterAutofacModules(containerBuilder);

    // register all automapper mappings as di services so there dependencies can be resolved
    ConfigureAutomapper(containerBuilder);

    ConfigureSwagger(services);

    // copy all asp core dependency injection registrations to autofac
    containerBuilder.Populate(services);
    IContainer container = containerBuilder.Build();

    return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }

    // make sure the database was created and all migrations applied
    MigrateDatabase(app);
    app.ApplicationServices.GetService<HoehenSuchtDbContext>().EnsureSeedData(env);

    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    ConfigureIdentityServer(app, Configuration);

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc();

    //app.UseSwaggerGen(/*routeTemplate: "docs/{apiVersion}/swagger.json"*/);
    //app.UseSwaggerUi(/*baseRoute: "docs", swaggerUrl: "docs/v1/swagger.json"*/);
}

public static Action<IServiceCollection, IConfigurationRoot> ConfigureEntityFrameworkDatabase = (services, config) =>
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<HoehenSuchtDbContext>(builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(config["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]))
        .AddDbContext<HoehenSuchtIdentityDbContext>(builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(config["Data:IdentityConnection:ConnectionString"]));
};

public static Action<IServiceCollection> ConfigureMvc = services =>
{
    services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices(new List<Assembly> { typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly });
};
```

I already tried registering a special test middleware that in theory should authenticate and set a claims principal. But somewhere down the OWIN pipeline the authentication is denied and I get a 401 error code.

This is how I setup the OWIN Test Server:

```
Startup.MigrateDatabase = app =>
{
    app.ApplicationServices.GetService<HoehenSuchtDbContext>().Database.EnsureCreated();
};
Startup.ConfigureEntityFrameworkDatabase = ApiTestServer.ConfigureInMemoryDatabase;
Startup.ConfigureIdentityServer = (app, config) =>
{
    app.ApplicationServices.GetService<HoehenSuchtDbContext>().EnsureSeedData(new HostingEnvironment {EnvironmentName = "development" });

    app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticatedTestRequestMiddleware>();
};
Server = new TestServer(TestServer.CreateBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
```

And this is my custom `AuthenticatedTestRequestMiddleware`:

```
public class AuthenticatedTestRequestMiddleware
{
    public const string TestingCookieAuthentication = "TestCookieAuthentication";
    public const string TestingHeader = "X-Integration-Testing";
    public const string TestingHeaderValue = "78EAAA45-E68B-43C7-9D12-3A5F1E646BD5";

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AuthenticatedTestRequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains(TestingHeader) && context.Request.Headers[TestingHeader].First().Equals(TestingHeaderValue))
        {
            // fake authenticated the user
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            claimsIdentity.AddClaims(new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, UserSeedData.AdminUserId)
            });
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
            context.User = claimsPrincipal;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

The principal is set and exists in the database with the given ID, but after I call `next(context)` I get an `401 Unauthorized` result.

How can I successfully fake authenticate the user and bypass the [Authorize] while also setting the current User for the HttpRequest?

**UPDATE:**
If I register my own CookieAuthentication handler like that:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticatedTestRequestMiddleware.TestingCookieAuthentication;
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
});
```

I get the `302 Redirect` to the login page. The signin however is working correctly when I use this inside the TestMiddleware `await context.Authentication.SignInAsync(TestingCookieAuthentication, claimsPrincipal)`

Comment: More answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112564/asp-net-disable-authentication-in-development-environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so I found out why it does not work :)

When creating the `ClaimsPrincipal` the AuthenticationProvider must be included in the constructor of the principal. If the authentication type is not provided the `SignInAsync()` function will fail and not authenticated the user.

Instead of doing this:

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, UserSeedData.AdminUserId)
});
```

You must specify the AuthenticationHandler like this:

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, UserSeedData.AdminUserId)
}, TestingCookieAuthentication);
```