# ASP.NET Core disable authentication in development environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

Is it possible to "disable" authentication in ASP.NET Core application without changing its logic?

I have a .net website which uses an external identity server app for authentication.
Anyway I would like to be able to mock the authentication when I'm developing it (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development), airing access to all actions ignoring the authorization attributes.

Is it possible to do it just mocking some services in the service collection?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can bypass authorization in development environment by applying [`AllowAnonymousAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.allowanonymousattribute) to your endpoints.

**.NET 6 (ASP.NET Core 6) and newer, `dotnet new webapi` template**
Use [`AllowAnonymous`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authorizationendpointconventionbuilderextensions.allowanonymous) method in `Program.cs` to apply `AllowAnonymousAttribute` to all controllers:

```cs
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    app.MapControllers().AllowAnonymous();
else
    app.MapControllers();
```

**.NET Core 3.0 - .NET 5 (ASP.NET Core 3.0-5), `dotnet new webapi` template**
Use [`WithMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.routingendpointconventionbuilderextensions.withmetadata) method in `Startup.Configure()` to apply `AllowAnonymousAttribute` to all controllers:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // preceding code omitted for brevity
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            endpoints.MapControllers().WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute());
        else
            endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

**Minimal API in .NET 6 (ASP.NET Core 6) and newer, `dotnet new webapi -minimal` template**
Use `AllowAnonymous` method to apply `AllowAnonymousAttribute` to a minimal API endpoint:

```cs
var hiEndpoint = app
    .MapGet("/hi", () => "Hello!")
    .RequireAuthorization();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    hiEndpoint.AllowAnonymous();
```

---

**Details**

`endpoints` and `app` from the examples above, both implement [`IEndpointRouteBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.iendpointroutebuilder) which has multiple `Map` extension methods like `MapControllers()` and `MapGet(...)` that return [`IEndpointConventionBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.iendpointconventionbuilder).

[`WithMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.routingendpointconventionbuilderextensions.withmetadata) (available since .NET Core 3.0) and [`AllowAnonymous`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authorizationendpointconventionbuilderextensions.allowanonymous) (available since .NET 5) are extensions for `IEndpointConventionBuilder` and can be called upon the results of those `Map` methods.

[`AllowAnonymousAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.allowanonymousattribute)'s description from the docs:

> Specifies that the class or method that this attribute is applied to does not require authorization.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for: disable authentication for development environment for .NET Core 3.x and WebApi. All other solutions were not working for me.

Comment: Works with latest asp.net core as of 9/20

Comment: I like this solution more as it leverages the Dotnetcore pipeline

Comment: I get an error, `IApplicationBuilder` does not have a definition for `Environment` () I injected it into configure, but it does not have `MapControllers` in asp core 6.0.1 I was not able to get past this

Comment: @Transformer, this is correct. In the first ASP.NET Core 6 example, `app` has type `WebApplication` and not `IApplicationBuilder`. Please use `dotnet new webapi` .NET 6 CLI command to check the types.

Comment: thanks will try that

Comment: in Net 6 and above MapControllers().AllowAnonymous() is accessible in app.UseEndpoints

Answer (score 70):

On updating to net core 3.1, the mvc `AllowAnonymousFilter` was not working for us any more. We found conditionally adding a custom `IAuthorizationHander` to be the simplest way forward to conditionally bypass auth.

eg.

```c#
/// <summary>
/// This authorisation handler will bypass all requirements
/// </summary>
public class AllowAnonymous : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        foreach (IAuthorizationRequirement requirement in context.PendingRequirements.ToList())
            context.Succeed(requirement); //Simply pass all requirements
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then register this handler conditionally in `Startup.ConfigureServices`.

```c#
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  {...}

  //Allows auth to be bypassed
  if (_env.IsDevelopment())
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AllowAnonymous>();
}
```

Note `AddAuthentication` and `AddAuthorization` services are still registered and configured as per prod code (which is nice).

To allow our unit test to bypass auth, we added a new anonymous testbase with a startup class that added this line without any conditions. Nice and simple!

Comment: Nice :) .Net Core 3.0 `IWebHostEnvironment` doesnt have `IsLocalDev()` method but it does have `IsDevelopment()` -- I personally just use `#if (DEBUG)` directive though

Comment: Yeah whoops, that is an extension method we have. eg:

`public static bool IsLocalDev(this IWebHostEnvironment environment) => environment.IsEnvironment("LocalDev");`

Comment: This definitely helped with 3.1 upgrade.  Not sure if this is a known issue?

Comment: The IPolicyEvaluator solution by ozzy is a better, cleaner approach.

Comment: Saved my time, nice one!

Comment: There's no need to use Linq and call .ToList() on context.PendingRequirements, because it is already IEnumerable, and can be iterated through by the foreach without conversion.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you are a lifesaver!! Perfect solution for integration tests.

Comment: There are lots of similar questions and answers to this problem on SO, but this one seems to be the most straightforward solution.

Comment: how to do this in `asp core 6 with endpointrouting`

Comment: While this works, You should never have testing code in your production code.

Answer (score 34):

Another solution you may want to consider is using the IPolicyEvaluator. This means that you can keep all the existing security elements.

```
public class DisableAuthenticationPolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
{
    public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
    {
        // Always pass authentication.
        var authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(), new AuthenticationProperties(), JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(authenticationTicket));
    }

    public async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object resource)
    {
        // Always pass authorization
        return await Task.FromResult(PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success());
    }
}
```

In the Startup.cs, ensure this appears at the top of the ConfigureServices method. Eg.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // Disable authentication and authorization.
            services.TryAddSingleton<IPolicyEvaluator, DisableAuthenticationPolicyEvaluator>();
        }
        ...
```

Rather than Startup.cs (and thanks to the comments below) if you are using Core 3.1 and you wish to use the WebApplicationFactory, you can do the following:

```
public class MyWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            // Disable Authentication.
            services.RemoveAll<IPolicyEvaluator>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPolicyEvaluator, DisableAuthenticationPolicyEvaluator>();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Best solution here and works with core 3.1.  Simple, elegant, reusable.

Comment: I had another `IPolicyEvaluator` injected by the prod `Startup` (using JWT) so I needed to `services.RemoveAll<IPolicyEvaluator>();` before `AddSingleton` .. not using TryAddSingleton is one less import, no need to try, and as I found, `TryAddSingleton` will indeed *not add the singleton* if there is already one registered

Comment: Works with core 5 as well

Comment: Very good solution indeed!

Comment: Little extension for `AuthenticateAsync`: get `string? userId = context.Request.Headers["development_user_id"];` and then pass it to `new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { new(ClaimTypes.Name, userId) }))`. This identity name will be available in controller in `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

Answer (score 18):

I've found sollution for this problem on [illucIT Blog](https://www.illucit.com/blog/2017/10/asp-net-core-2-0-disable-authentication-development-environment/#respond).

This code must work:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
   services.AddMvc(opts =>
   {
      opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
   });
} else {
   services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: This does not work in latest .net core because `IHostingEnvironment` is not passed to `ConfigureServices`

Comment: @Dagrooms you can inject `IHostingEnvironment` to `Startup` constructor and use it in `ConfigureServices` ;)

Comment: Yep, figured that out after scanning through docs, it's surprisingly hard to find good info

Answer (score 8):

It's tricky to give a detailed answer without more details on your end, but I have previously achieved this by conditionally registering:

- the external authentication middleware
- the global policy that requires an authenticated request

it looked something like:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Environment = env;
    }

    public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(x =>
        {
            if (!Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var authenticatedUserPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();

                x.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authenticatedUserPolicy));
            }
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        if (!Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // Register external authentication middleware
        }

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

In my case, the authorization filter was applied globally, so every single action of the MVC app required an authenticated user.

If you have different requirements - fine-grained `[Authorize]` attributes on some actions - then you could probably achieve the same result by changing how the associated authorization policies are built. They could basically contain no requirements at all.

```cs
AuthorizationPolicy yourCustomPolicy = null;
if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    yourCustomPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().Build();
}
else
{
    yourCustomPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        // chaining appropriate methods to suit your needs
        .Build();
}
```

Comment: It looks exactly what I'm searching for. I'll test it

Comment: This solution may work with ASP.NET Core 1.x, but in ASP.NET Core 2.0, they have change the authentication pipeline. What works for me in 2.0 is this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156927/1118893

Comment: Could you let me know what you think doesn't work? I'm using this technique in ASP.NET Core 2.0 with success.

Answer (score 5):

In ASP.NET Core 6, we managed to disable the authorization without changing any other part from the productive code, just the following logic in Program.cs:

```
if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapControllers();
}
else
{
    app.MapControllers().AllowAnonymous();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to clarify @Kirill Lutsenko's answer about the method he found on the [IllucIT blog post](https://www.illucit.com/en/asp-net/asp-net-core-2-0-disable-authentication-development-environment/) (note that in my case this is for .NET Core 2.0.  I see other answers saying the `AllowAnonymousFilter` method won't work in .NET Core 3.1):

The Startup class has an overloaded constructor.  One of the overloads takes an `IHostingEnvironment` parameter.  You need to use this version of the constructor.

In the Startup class create a property of type `IHostingEnvironment`.  Call it, say, `Environment`.  Then set that property in the constructor.

Then, in the `ConfigureServices` method, you can use `Environment.IsDevelopment()`.

```
public class Startup
{        
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        Environment = environment;
    }
    
    public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            // This uses the Environment property populated in the constructor.
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
            }
            
            // Set other options here.  For example:
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new UTCDateTimeModelBinderProvider());
            //...
        });
        
        //...
    }
}
```

As a side note, in real life we use a different overload of the constructor, which takes both an `IConfiguration` object and an `IHostingEnvironment` object as parameters.  That allows us to configure services based on an appsettings.json configuration file.

For example:

```
public class Startup
{        
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = environment;
    }
    
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...

        // Data access via Entity Framework
        services.AddDbContext<ContainersDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OrdersDatabase"));
        });
        
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this thread comes up if you're looking up the error "System.NotSupportedException: Negotiate authentication requires a server that supports IConnectionItemsFeature like Kestrel." with .Net 7, the only way I was able to get around this issue with an MVC .Net Core project was to change my Program.cs.

Basically, removing the Authentication from the Services.

Note:  You will have to manage your web apps launchSettings.json file and it's ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT values.  Which will be a part of your deployment.

Original Program.cs code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

New Code:

```
if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Net6 and above use :

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    if (env.EnvironmentName == "Development")
    {    
        endpoints.MapControllers().AllowAnonymous();       
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to use magic string. Juste use `app.Environment.IsDevelopment()` to check if environment is Development. You can also use `IsStaging()` and `IsProduction` to check for Staging and Production environments.