# Disable authentication in Asp.Net Core 3.0 for development

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

How can I disable authentication during development for controllers that have an `[Authorize]` attribute?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112564/asp-net-disable-authentication-in-development-environment) is an answer for .net core 2, but it uses `AddMvc()` which isn't in use in .net core 3.0.

I tried this:

```cs
    services.AddControllers().AddMvcOptions(opts => opts.Filters.Add<AllowAnonymousFilter>());
```

It still returned a 401; I don't know if that's even on the right track.

#### Update:

The previously linked post has been updated with answers that work with 3.x.

[Asp.net "disable" authentication in development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112564/asp-net-disable-authentication-in-development-environment)

Comment: `services.AddMvc()` is in .net core 3.0 under the extension `MvcServiceCollectionExtensions`. You can use same approach as in `.net core 2` to achieve what you need.

Comment: @Venky It doesn't actually work, likely because the rest of the application is not set up in the `AddMvc` pattern. Even if it did, I would feel uncomfortable using it because `AddMvc` seems to no longer be a recommended pattern, and has been replaced, in this case, by `AddControllers`.

Comment: Applying the `[AllowAnonymous]` filter as a way to ease development is really not a good idea since you are skipping important parts of your application while *not* providing the information you may rely on when the user is actually authenticated. So it is a better idea to sign in as a synthetic user that contains the claims you need and have the authorization work as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
public class Startup 
{
   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = env;
   }

   public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
            services.AddControllers(opts =>
            {
                if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    opts.Filters.Add<AllowAnonymousFilter>();
                }
                else
                {
                  var authenticatedUserPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                            .Build();
                  opts.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authenticatedUserPolicy)); 
                 }
            });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work. My only issue with it is that it applies authorization to every controller, instead of allowing more fine-grained control of where to apply the `[Authorize]` attribute. I would still appreciate a solution that works more similarly to the .net core 2 method.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to launchSettings.json in your project:

[image: 1]

then set "anonymousAuthentication" to "true".

Answer (score 0):

How about automatically logging the user in with "test" Claim information when in development. For example, let's say when you are in non-development environments you use something like below to authorize a user:

```
// Checked the database and user is legit so populate the claims
// Create the identity for the user. userList is var or list populated from database. userEmail is the user's email or some other identifier.
identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userList.fullname),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userList.userrole),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userEmail),
}, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
var login = HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

When you are in development you can do something like:

```
// You may need to inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment. I use .Net core 2.2 so not sure about 3.
if (env.EnvironmentName == "Development")
{
    // In Development so create "test" claim information and automatically authorize the user
    // Create the identity for the user
    identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test User"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Tester"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "tester@test.com"),
    }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    // Populate the session user name
    HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionUserName, userList.fullname);

    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var login = HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do this because the authentication is handled by a different project; this project is only a consumer. I'm looking for a way to simply bypass the `[Authorize]` attribute as is shown in the linked question for .net core 2.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. If you are able to bypass authentication for a project that you don't control isn't that a big security issue? Are you looking to exploit a vulnerability? Would it be better to ask the creator of that other project to create a role or add simple logic for development?

Comment: I control my project, but it doesn't do any of the work in adding claims or creating users. My project only reads the _existing_ claims off of a cookie, which doesn't require any claims based work. I therefore don't want to start adding irrelevant claims code into my project.