# How to write a controller test while using bearer authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

This is how my controller looks like:

```
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
    [ApiController]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("/api/account/{accountId}/service")]
    public class MyServiceController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMyService _service;

        public MyServiceController(IMyService service)
        {
            this._service = service;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<SomeDto>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<SomeDto>> GetAllServicesAsync([FromRoute] string accountId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await this._application.GetServicesAsync(accountId, cancellationToken);
        }
```

and a test that looks like this:

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetAllAsyncTest()
        {
            var expected = new SomeDto { AccountId = "123" };

            this._mockApplication.Setup(service => service.GetSomesAsync(expected.AccountId, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(new List<SomeDto> { expected });
            var client = this._factory.MockService(this._mockApplication).CreateClient();
            var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync($"/api/account/{expected.AccountId}/account");
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var actual = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<SomeDto>>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

            actual.Should().HaveCount(1).And.ContainEquivalentOf(expected);
        }
```

I just added `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` and it works great when I start my server. The problem is that my test fails with this:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

If I remove back the `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` my test passes by my endpoints are not authenticated.

How can I make this test pass? I tried:

- giving it a real JWT token
- mocking the auth part
- disabling the authentication with AllowAnonymousFilter like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441542/1387563
- using a policy https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2913#issuecomment-369922222

All attempts failed. Either the test passes or the authentication works. Never both.
How can I make this test pass while keeping authentication?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed only my test and it worked.

```
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                {
                    services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IPolicyEvaluator), typeof(DisableAuthenticationPolicyEvaluator), ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
                    services.AddScoped<IDbContextProvider, DbContextProvider>();
                });
            });
```

```
    public class DisableAuthenticationPolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
    {
        public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
        {
            // Always pass authentication.
            var authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(), new AuthenticationProperties(), "Bearer");
            return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(authenticationTicket));
        }

        public async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object resource)
        {
            // Always pass authorization
            return await Task.FromResult(PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success());
        }
    }
```