# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false, even when I have a cookie set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I know a couple of questions with similar title are already being asked. By they are related to ASP.NET and not ASP.NET Core Identity. Thus they can't help me.

I sign in my user using this method:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
```

And I can verify that the HTTP Response header contains `Set-Cookie` header field. And it's as follow:

```
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8DQK2l...
```

And then I call another API to access `User.Identity` and I can see that HTTP Request sends the authentication cookie back to server. But I see that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false.

Why is it so?

Comment: Authentication/Authorization doesn't run by default. What happens if you add an `[Authorize]` attribute to the Controller/Action?

Comment: How does your `Startup` class's `ConfigureServices` method look like? Perhaps you're missing some configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112564/asp-net-disable-authentication-in-development-environment). The two that caught my eye are the following:

1. [answer from simon hooper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59558348/9711951)

Create a `IAuthorizationHandler` singleton service that allows anonymous logins in development environments

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This authorisation handler will bypass all requirements
/// </summary>
public class AllowAnonymous : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        foreach (IAuthorizationRequirement requirement in context.PendingRequirements.ToList())
            context.Succeed(requirement); //Simply pass all requirements

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then register this handler conditionally in `Startup.ConfigureServices`.

```cs
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  {...}

  //Allows auth to be bypassed
  if (_env.IsDevelopment())
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AllowAnonymous>();
}
```

2. [answer from ozzy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314486/9711951)

Another solution you may want to consider is using the IPolicyEvaluator. This means that you can keep all the existing security elements.

```cs
    public class DisableAuthenticationPolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
    {
        public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
        {
            // Always pass authentication.
            var authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(), new AuthenticationProperties(), JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(authenticationTicket));
        }

        public async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object resource)
        {
            // Always pass authorization
            return await Task.FromResult(PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success());
        }
    }
```

In the `Startup.cs`, ensure this appears at the top of the ConfigureServices method. Eg.

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // Disable authentication and authorization.
                services.TryAddSingleton<IPolicyEvaluator, DisableAuthenticationPolicyEvaluator>();
            }
            ...
```